# Getting data relations by javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

> Sorry for title I really didn't know how to describe it.

I have data returned by JavaScript but my data has other data ORM related which i need those as well.

this is my data that returned on selected option:

```
Object { id: 1, address: "hrktgui erhoutruei9utgy", postalcode: "154785", user_id: 1, city_id: 1, state_id: 10, country_id: 102, created_at: "2018-02-09 13:28:22", updated_at: "2018-02-09 13:28:22" }
```

**I need this data:**

1. address
2. postalcode
3. city name (provided under city_id)
4. state name (provided under state_id)

> **My issue is to retrieving that city and state name**

later i want add this 4 data as hidden input to my view so I can use it for my other function.

here is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="address_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var addressID = $(this).val();
      if(addressID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('addressdetails') }}/'+encodeURI(addressID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('div#details').empty();
        console.log(data['address']);
        console.log(data);
        // $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        //     $('div#details').append('<input type="hidden" name="shipment_price" value="'+...+'"><input type="hidden" name="shipment_price" value="'+...+'">');
        //     });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('div#details').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

my html:

```
<div id="details"></div>
```

my function:

```
public function getAddressDetails($id)
{
        $address = Address::findOrFail($id);
        return response()->json($address);
}
```

my route:

```
Route::get('addressdetails/{id}', 'CartController@getAddressDetails');
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question? it is not very clear what you want to get done.

Comment: @AniruddhaGohad my issue is to retrieving that city and state names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its an object. try this.

```
success:function(data) {
        var statename = data.state.name;
        var cityname = data.city.name;
}
```

**Edit:**
"my issue is to retrieving that city and state names"

your query need to use eager loading

example:

```
return response()->json(Address::with(['city','state'])->find($id));
```

in Address Model

```
class Address {
      ...
      ...
      public function city(){
          return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
      }
      public function state(){
          return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
      }
}
```

Comment: this i get is not problem, my issue is to retrieving that city and state names

Comment: it seem working however i have tiny issue remained, my dropdown will load with default selected option and if user want can change it if not will stay the same. the issue is i need get this data even if user not try to change option, something like when page loads. i tried `$('select[name="address_id"]').on('load', function() ` but doesn't work

Comment: oh.. just use `$('select[name="address_id"]').trigger('change');`.. is this what you want?

Comment: no that won't work either, it's fine i added empty option on top now they are force to select :)  thank you.